# Calculus 3 Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

My goal is to find the length of a diagonal for a box with certain values. Question is below.

I was able to find the Volume, the surface area, and I did similar to find the diagonal but I still ran into issues here.

I took the derivative of

$$L^2=l^2+w^2+h^2$$

and came up with the equation

$$\frac{dL}{dt} = \frac{dL}{dl}\frac{dl}{dt}+\frac{dL}{dw}\frac{dw}{dt}+\frac{dL}{dh}\frac{dh}{dt}$$

I then plugged in the values and then got

$$2L\frac{dL}{dt}=2l\frac{dl}{dt}+2w\frac{dw}{dt}+2h\frac{dh}{dt}$$

I then did $((2*3)(6)+(2*7)(6)+(2*7)(-9))(2(3)) = -1$. This value didn't work, I tried it without dividing by the $2L (-6)$ and I have tried $0$ and $-1$ as well when I got frustrated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The length $l$, width $w$, and height $h$ of a box change with time. At a certain instant the dimensions are $l$ = $3 m$ and $w$ $=$ $h$ $=$ $7 m$, and $l$ and $w$ are increasing at a rate of $6$ $\frac{m}{s}$ while $h$ is decreasing at a rate of $9$ $\frac{m}{s}$. At that instant find the rates at which the following quantities are changing.

(a) The volume.
Correct: 231

(b) The surface area.
Correct: 108

(c) The length of a diagonal. (Round the answer to two decimal places.)
?

Comment: This is very difficult to read. Could you use latex please?

Comment: Someone formatted it, not sure who but thank you <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation $$2L\frac{dL}{dt}=2l\frac{dl}{dt}+2w\frac{dw}{dt}+2h\frac{dh}{dt}$$ appears correct. After substituting values for $l,w,h,\dfrac{dl}{dt}$ etc. you get $$2L\frac{dL}{dt} = -6.$$ At the time in question, $L=\sqrt{l^2+w^2+h^2} = \sqrt{3^2+7^2+7^2}=\sqrt{107}$, so $$\frac{dL}{dt} = \frac{-6}{2L} = \frac{-6}{2\sqrt{107}} \approx -0.29$$

Your first attempt currently reads:

> $((2*3)(6)+(2*7)(6)+(2*7)(-9))(2(3)) = -1$

which looks like a typo for:

> $\dfrac{((2*3)(6)+(2*7)(6)+(2*7)(-9))}{2(3)} = -1$

which suggests you mixed up $L$ (the diagonal) with $l=3$ (the length).

And to be picky, when you write:

> $$\frac{dL}{dt} = \frac{dL}{dl}\frac{dl}{dt}+\frac{dL}{dw}\frac{dw}{dt}+\frac{dL}{dh}\frac{dh}{dt}$$

you should use partial derivatives, i.e.:

$$\frac{dL}{dt} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial l}\frac{dl}{dt}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial w}\frac{dw}{dt}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial h}\frac{dh}{dt}$$

Great work -- you got nearly all the way to the correct answer!